# Regex to pull the URL site name from block of text?

Tags: regex

I don't know too much about regex, I've mostly just used RegExr to guess & check and come up with suitable expressions for my needs.  I've made a notification reader on my phone using Tasker, and I want to use Regex to replace URLs with just the site name, for example:

"New message from <person>: Hey check this out [https://www.youtube.com/watch?=whatever"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?=whatever%22)

I would want to replace the URL with **"link from youtube.com"** in order to make it sound less annoying, especially when someone sends an extremely long link, say from Amazon or Facebook.

I'm fairly certain Tasker can utilize regex return values, so I'd like to use that to my advantage to pull the URL out of the text and return just the site's name, regardless of what URL is sent.

Can anyone help me build an appropriate expression for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which software, what kind of input and output (files?), more details please.

Comment: It's Tasker, as I mentioned, and it would be getting input similar to what I wrote in the first quotation, as the input is compiled together through a series of actions based on the incoming notification.  It would first compile the title and body of the notification into a syntax like that, then use the regex on it.  Output would be speaking it directly using WaveNet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  I used this regex:

`(https?:\/\/([^\/ \n\r]*)((([^\. \n\r]*)\.?)*)[^ \n\r]*)`

and this for the replace

`(link from $2)`

and it works pretty well.  It still has some trouble getting URLs out of some spots, but most of the time it works and that's pretty much all I wanted.  If you know a more elegant solution please let me know, but for now this should be fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
https?://([^/]+)\S*
```

or

```
https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\S*
```

if you can't choose the delimiter

and replace with: `(link from $1)`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pkqWW6/1)